# different handling of nan values of a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

i have a df like this:

```
      A    B 
 0    1    5
 1    1    7
 2  NaN  NaN
 3    1    8
 4  NaN  NaN
 5  NaN  NaN
 6    2    6
 7    2    2
 8  NaN  NaN
 9  NaN  NaN
10    2    3
```

now I want to fill the nan values within an event differently than the outside. An event is identified by column A and has the same value (in my example there are events 1 and 2). The column A should simply contain the event number within an event. For column B, the last entry within an event should be transferred.
Between the events the NaN values should be set to '0'.

I tried `ffill()` and `fillna()`, but can´t match it with my conditions.

Expectet outcome:

```
      A    B 
 0    1    5
 1    1    7
 2    1    7
 3    1    8
 4    0    0
 5    0    0
 6    2    6
 7    2    2
 8    2    2
 9    2    2
10    2    3
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) with helper groups created by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and compared by backfiiling values for prevent omit values between groups, last replace missing values to `0` and to integers:

```
s = df.A.ffill()
g = df.A.mask(s.eq(df.A.bfill()), s)
df = df.groupby(g).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B
0   1  5
1   1  7
2   1  7
3   1  8
4   0  0
5   0  0
6   2  6
7   2  2
8   2  2
9   2  2
10  2  3
```

Comment: i have also tried it on a df where column A contains data of type datetime and additionally the df consists of more than 2 columns - here the schema didn't work despite adaptation. can you tell me why?

Comment: @Vini - Hard question, it seems data relate issue, is possible create data sample with problematic and convert to dict? Like df.to_dict(orient='list')` for check types of data, if NaNs are not strings and similar.